# Reference the value of another spreadsheet file

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2013

I'm triying to reference the value of a cell that is in another spreadsheet file.
I know that I can do by using

```
=[file.xlsx]Worksheet!A1
```

But the file name is hardcoded in the formula and what I want is to reference it as a named cell. So suppose I define B1 as a named cell called "FileName". Then I try:

```
=[FileName]Worksheet!A1
```

I get a #REF error.

How can I use the value of a named cell to reference another file?

Comment: see [**this**](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/various-ways-to-pull-data-from-another-workbook-closedopened/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `INDIRECT`.

```
=INDIRECT("'[" &B2 & "]worksheet'!$A$1")
```

..then replace the worksheet name.